# Textbox clears value on tab

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

When I enter any pincode it will automatically fill city in textbox next to pincode. but when I press tab to go on textbox of city it clears city in that text box. How can i prevent this??

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="input-group" ng-class="{'error':employeeForm.pin_code.$touched && employeeForm.pin_code.$invalid }">
         <span class="input-group-addon">Pincode<span style="color:red">*</span></span>
             <input type="text" id="pincode" ng-readonly="contactReadonly" ng-keydown = "user.city = ''" ng-keyup="employeeForm.pincode.$viewValue.length > 5 && search(user.pincode,'city')" name="pincode" maxlength="6" autocomplete="off" ng-model="user.pincode" placeholder="121038" class="form-control digits" required>
    </div>
    <span ng-show="pincodeError" style="color: red" ng-cloak>{{pincodeErrorMsg}}</span>
</div>

 <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="input-group" ng-class="{'error':employeeForm.city.$touched && employeeForm.city.$invalid }">
        <span class="input-group-addon">City<span style="color:red">*</span></span>
           <input type="text" id="city" ng-change = "cityChangeEvent()"   style="text-transform: capitalize;"  name="city" class="form-control only_name" placeholder="Your city" ng-model="user.city" required>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code `ng-keydown = "user.city = ''"` sets the city input field to empty on every keydown-press, this also includes tab, when the pincode field is in focus. You either need to remove this part of the code, or evaluate the key pressed, and do nothing if the key is tab, or any other you want to prevent.

Comment: Ohh got it .Thanks @Ole